# What does "! []" Elm code syntax in Todomvc mean

Tags: elm

Coming from react, I am learning to understand Elm.

In the [Todomvc example code](https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc/blob/master/Todo.elm), there is the following code snippet:

```
-- How we update our Model on a given Msg?
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp ->
      model ! []        <-- What is this?
```

What I (think I) understand, is that the `update` function takes in a `msg` of type `Msg` and a `model` of type `Model`, and returns a tuple of containing a `Model` and a `Cmd Msg`.

But how should I read the return statement?

```
model ! []
```

What does this statement mean? return a "model [something] empty list"?
Did I miss something in the docs where this is explained? (Googling "elm !" did not get me far :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Update for Elm 0.19**

Elm 0.19 has removed the exclamation point operator. You must now construct the tuple manually, as in `(model, Cmd.none)`.

**Original Answer for Elm 0.18**

The exclamation point in `model ! []` is just a short-hand function for `(model, Cmd.batch [])`, which is the type returned from typical `update` statements. [It is defined here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#!)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I did come across the cryptic `(!) : model -> List (Cmd msg) -> (model, Cmd msg)` line, but I couldn't translate it to `model ! []` Hopefully more docs will follow. Feels like a promising language so far.

Comment: That's one of the major problem with elm. How one is going to search on the web an exclamation mark "!"? I tried searching around ten variations of "elm-lang exclamation mark". I even searched "haskell exclamation mark". Why can't we write `(model, Cmd.batch [])` as it is? It makes it lot less magical. Even if you have to make it "less cody", then shouldn't infix operator with a word be used like ``someOperator``? Just some thoughts.

Comment: You can use the Elm Packages Fancy Search (Go to [Elm Packages](http://package.elm-lang.org/) and click on [Fancy Search](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/)) to find functions like that. [Here you can search on `!`](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=!) and it pulls up the correct function.

Comment: Oh great. Didn't know about that. That helps! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You Elm folks are so freaking quick. :)

Comment: If `!` is defined `(!) : model -> List (Cmd msg) -> (model, Cmd msg`, why calling it like `model ! []` rather then `! model []`? Why can some functions appear between the arguments and others cannot?

Comment: @Chris.Zou because some functions can be used between the 2 arguments (infix is the term). So `(!) model []` is the same as `model ! []`. Most basic examples are math functions like `+` etc. I think if the function is defined between parentheses, then you can use them between the two arguments.

Comment: FWIW I found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/AXJdAKf4Mbg/MSuw9Y4NCwAJ) helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Note that this syntax is going away in the next version of Elm (0.19) so don't get into the habit of using it ;-)

You can use today, and with 0.19:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: Could you please provide us an alternative?

Comment: @Astrowie Instead of `model ! [cmd1, cmd2]` you use `(model, Cmd.batch [cmd1, cmd2])`